# Enable dual input pairs using xinput and related tools

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, touchpad, xinput, wireless-keyboards

I've been unable to get this working, just the second pointer shows up and blinks. Please note that I have a dual monitor, single GPU layout. I'm not sure if the problem isn't related to the XOrg config (shown). Any and all help & encouragement appreciated. Thank you.

Here is the `xinput` with the wireless usb device plugged in.

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                              id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                    id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                      id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                             id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard                   id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                                  id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                                  id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

I then enter the following commands, and see the resulting `xinput`, and I see the other pointer on the screen, either as a cursor or standard pointer, and it is blinking, and it jitters as i type on the first, wired usb keyboard, but the neither the touchpad or the keyboard of the wireless device are working as might be expected.  It's a Microsoft All-in-one Media Keyboard. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 (and I feel I should note I chose the "minimal install" from the start.) It may also be of note that I'm using two monitors from 1 16-lane GPU. Thank you for any help you can give.

```
$ xinput create-master wireless
$ xinput reattach 10 16
$ xinput reattach 11 16
$ xinput reattach 9 17
$ xinput reattach 15 17


⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ CHICONY USB Keyboard                      id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
⎡ wireless pointer                                  id=16   [master pointer  (17)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=10   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎜   ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=11   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎜   ↳ wireless XTEST pointer                        id=18   [slave  pointer  (16)]
⎣ wireless keyboard                                 id=17   [master keyboard (16)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=9    [slave  keyboard (17)]
    ↳ Microsoft Microsoft® Nano Transceiver v2.0    id=15   [slave  keyboard (17)]
    ↳ wireless XTEST keyboard                       id=19   [slave  keyboard (17)]
```

#### /etc/X11/xorg.com

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 396.54  (buildd@lgw01-amd64-044)  Tue Aug 21 18:18:46 UTC 2018

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 396.54  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-14)  Wed Aug 15 00:22:27 PDT 2018

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer AL2223W"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 82.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1070"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: nvidia-auto-select +1440+0, DVI-D-0: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just noticed the power on switch on the right edge. It is well.